# What does each of these sentences mean?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, sentence-meaning

What does each of these sentences mean? What are differences in meaning between them? Are they all grammatically correct?

> 1. I practiced martial arts **at a** young age.
> 2. I practiced martial arts **since a** young age.
> 3. I practiced martial arts **from a** young age.

Answer (score 1):

> I practiced martial arts at a young age.

means that at some point in your youth, you practiced martial arts for a while.  It could be a long time, it could be a short time, it's not clear.

> I practiced martial arts since a young age.

is nonsense, it doesn't mean anything.  But I think you intend it to mean the same as the next sentence.

> I practiced martial arts from a young age.

means that at some point in your youth, you started practicing martial arts.  The implication is that you never stopped practicing martial arts.  I.e., that you have practiced martial arts since you were young.

Comment: Good answer, although I wouldn't say the 2nd sentence is "nonsense", merely ungrammatical.  It could easily be made grammatical again by adding the word "have", as in "I have practiced martial arts since a young age."  Then it would have more or less the same meaning as the 3rd sentence.